# How to extract currency from a string

Tags: apex, string

I need to extract the currency code (which code be $ or £ or USD or GBP etc) from a string which could be like $1,780 or USD1,780.

Would anyone be able to suggest the best way to write apex code that can handle all cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your nomenclature isn't clear.

When you say "wesbite" do you mean your visualforce page?

If "yes", you don't need to do anything special. You can get the currency (after enabled like @dhanajay-patil said) by querying the `CurrencyISOCode` field on the object. You can also get query the field value as a number. The currency prefix isn't part of the actual field value...that only gets rendered on a page if/when you are using the `apex:outputField` (or similar) tag.

If "no", then I am confused. Are you saying you have an external website, that needs to pass data to Salesforce? If this website is in an iframe or embedded in a canvas, I don't think you will be able to fetch the values from it and pass them into into your VF page, due to cross site scripting issues.

If you could be a bit clearer about what your "website" is, and what the make-up of your page is, we can possibly try to help further

UPDATE:

javascript regex match from first digit onwards e.g.

```
var str = "USD123.50"; 
var res = str.match(/[0-9].*/g);
```

This will return `123.50`, which you can use as you like

Comment: Thanks Sunny and sorry for the confusion. Yes it is an external site that I am able to fetch data from currently into a visualforce page. The challenge is extracting the currency symbol.

Comment: ok, so if you're wanting to do this in pure javascript, a regex substring, for everything after the first digit, should work. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write an apex code.Simply enable Currency for your org.
To Enable Currency **goto Setup-->Company Profile-->Manage Currencies.** then enable it.
Define a Currency that you want to add in your org.Make Sure your conversion rate should be proper.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This piece of code is actually part of an apex class where I am fetching some value from the website and splicing the data to display in a certain way within a JS frame in Salesforce.